# How can I keep hover state on unhover until page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this to work properly. I just want to make .accordion-content stay upon unhover. I've tried several approaches to this and now I'm pretty much at a total loss. Here is the code I'm working with:

HTML

```
<ul class="accordion-thing">
<li>
    <a>How do I setup my Chem+Nect Drum?<span>Learn More</span></a>
    <ul class="accordion-content">
        <li><em>01</em></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.accordion-thing,
.accordion-thing ul,
.accordion-thing li,
.accordion-thing a,
.accordion-thing span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.accordion-thing li {
    list-style: none !important;
}

.accordion-thing li > a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 910px;
    min-height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;

    color: #fdfdfd;
    font: bold 16px/42px Arial, sans-serif !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35) !important;

    background: #6c6e74;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%) !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51)) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%) !important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%) !important;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.accordion-thing li > a span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    font: normal bold 14px/18px Arial, sans-serif !important;
    background: #404247;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.accordion-content li a {
    color: #797979;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

    background: #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.accordion-content li:last-child a { border: none; }

.accordion-content li > a span {
    color: #797979;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.accordion-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: o;
    left: 0
    margin-left: 14px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

.accordion-thing > li:hover > a,
.accordion-thing > li:target > a {
    color: #00334c;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

    background: #0679b9 !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0679b9 0%, #3b59e2 100%) !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0679b9), color-stop(100%,#3b59e2)) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0679b9 0%,#3b59e2 100%) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top #0679b9 0%,#3b59e2 100%) !important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top #0679b9 0%,#3b59e2 100%) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(top #0679b9 0%,#3b59e2 100%) !important;
}

.accordion-thing > li:hover > a span,
.accordion-thing > li:target > a span {
    color: #fdfdfd !important;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);
    background: #00334c;
}

.accordion-content li:hover a { background: #efefef; }

.accordion-thing li > .accordion-content {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion-thing li:hover > .accordion-content {
    height: 98px;
}
```

Is there some Javascript I can add to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the hover style applied permanently after the first hover until the page refreshes, you will have to use javascript:

```
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-thing')[0];
accordion.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    this.classList.add('hovered');
});
```

then in your css, anywhere that you have `.accordion-thing li:hover {}`, you can change that to `.accordion-thing.hovered li {}`

[Here is a simple example to show this concept.](http://jsbin.com/ujAWiQI/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kavun. It works here:

http://jsbin.com/EGaLurur/1/edit?html,css,js,output

However, it doesn't work on my actual site:

http://chatasolutions.com/frequently-asked-questions

Any advice, Kavun? Thank you again.

Comment: You are including the `accordion-stay.js` file at the top of the page before the DOM is loaded, but you will need to execute that file after the DOM is loaded (put it at the bottom of the page) so that `document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-thing')` finds the `accordion-thing`

Comment: Although, wouldn't expanding the accordion on `click` instead of `mouseenter` be a better experience?

Comment: Thank you so much, Kavun. Worked perfectly. Also, you're absolutely right about expanding on click. I was having trouble implementing it that way, so I thought I'd use this as a workaround. I'll give it another try. Thank you again, Kavun.